# Jetpack Compose. Force switch night/notnight resources

Tags: android, android-resources, android-jetpack-compose, android-theme

Initially, the theme of my application followed the theme of the system, for convenience I created drawable resources for light and dark themes. Then I implemented the ability to change the theme manually regardless of the system theme, but apparently the drawable resources are tied to the system theme or something else. Is there a way to force-switch between night and notnight drawable resources somehow?

Answer (score 7):

Found a solution, correct me if something is wrong.

1. Inherit our Activity from AppCompatActivity instead of ComponentActivity
2. Use AppDelegateCompat.setDefaultNightMode() tell the application which theme we are going to use
3. Call delegate.applyDayNight()

   ```
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        // Getting user's saved selection
        appTheme.value = runBlocking(Dispatchers.IO) {
            getSavedAppTheme(context)
        }
        // Telling the application which mode to use
        when (appTheme.value) {
            AppTheme.SYSTEM_THEME -> AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_FOLLOW_SYSTEM)
            AppTheme.NIGHT_THEME  -> AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES)
            AppTheme.LIGHT_THEME  -> AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO)
        }
        delegate.applyDayNight()
        setContent {
            MyAppTheme {
                MyAppComposable()
            }
        }
    }
   ```

Handling user selection:

```
    suspend fun setAppTheme(context: Context, theme: AppTheme) {
        // Saving selection to cache 
        saveAppTheme(context, theme)
        // Applying selection
        appTheme.value = theme
        // Telling the application which mode to use
        when (appTheme.value) {
            AppTheme.SYSTEM_THEME -> setDefaultNightMode(MODE_NIGHT_FOLLOW_SYSTEM)
            AppTheme.NIGHT_THEME  -> setDefaultNightMode(MODE_NIGHT_YES)
            AppTheme.LIGHT_THEME  -> setDefaultNightMode(MODE_NIGHT_NO)
        }
    }
```

**UPD:**

Point 2 is better to call in Application.onCreate() so as not to reload Activity inside onCreate()

Comment: Using AppCompatActivity instead of ComponentActivity did the trick. Well played!

Answer (score -1):

What you can do is use [Data Store](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/datastore) and assign the value of that toggle to it. Then in your `setContent {}` you can check it as :

```
val theme = userSettings.themeStream.collectAsState()
            val useDarkColors = when (theme.value) {
                AppTheme.MODE_AUTO -> isSystemInDarkTheme()
                AppTheme.MODE_DAY -> false
                AppTheme.MODE_NIGHT -> true
            }
```

Where userSettings is :

```
enum class AppTheme {
    MODE_DAY,
    MODE_NIGHT,
    MODE_AUTO;

    companion object {
        fun fromOrdinal(ordinal: Int) = values()[ordinal]
    }
}

interface UserSettings {
    val themeStream: StateFlow<AppTheme>
    var theme: AppTheme
}

class UserSettingsImpl @Inject constructor(
    @ApplicationContext context: Context
) : UserSettings {

    override val themeStream: MutableStateFlow<AppTheme>
    override var theme: AppTheme by AppThemePreferenceDelegate("app_theme", AppTheme.MODE_AUTO)

    private val preferences: SharedPreferences =
        context.getSharedPreferences("sample_theme", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)

    init {
        themeStream = MutableStateFlow(theme)
    }

    inner class AppThemePreferenceDelegate(
        private val name: String,
        private val default: AppTheme,
    ) : ReadWriteProperty<Any?, AppTheme> {

        override fun getValue(thisRef: Any?, property: KProperty<*>): AppTheme =
            AppTheme.fromOrdinal(preferences.getInt(name, default.ordinal))

        override fun setValue(thisRef: Any?, property: KProperty<*>, value: AppTheme) {
            themeStream.value = value
            preferences.edit {
                putInt(name, value.ordinal)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then it should take the one stored in `Data Store` instead of using the system one.

Here's a full example [Compose theme switcher](https://github.com/stefanosansone/compose-theme-switcher) from [Stefano Sansone](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16279195/stefano-sansone)

Also you could take a read on [Jetpack Compose Theming](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/jetpack-compose-theming#3)

Comment: If I understand correctly, then this is the answer to the fact that the application remembers the theme selected by the user and stores the selection in the "cache". I have implemented this, but my problem is that at a low level the application is using the OS theme to use the corresponding Resources. For example, it turns out that the standard theme on the OS is daytime, and the user selected the night theme in the settings of my application, but the application still uses Resources(I.e. images) from the folder for the daytime theme